# What To Add In Config.ini File In Java RCP Application To Take JRE 1.6?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, config, java

I have multiple JRE installed in my machine (Jre 1.6 and Jre 1.7). I build my application with Jre 1.6.
But When I launch my java RCP application, it always takes Jre 1.7.

Can I add something in my config.ini file to always make it launch with Jre 1.6 ?
Can I make it take Jre 1.6 as Jre 1.6 is used to build the code ?

Answer (score 2):

you have to use -vm option in eclipse.ini as below.

```
-vm
jre6/bin/javaw.exe
```

User can also change the path information with the absolute location of other JDK/JRE installed under his local system.
For e.g. in Windows we can have

```
-vm
C:/Java/JDK16/bin/javaw.exe
```

for more help see the [link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/%C2%A0eclipse.ini).